# Counting certain partitions of integers

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, integer-partitions, lattice-orders

[Recall that] Young's lattice is a partially ordered set in which all partitions of integers are ordered thus: The elements just one step below any partition are those that you can get by subtracting $1$ from any of the terms (including terms equal to $1$, so one of those disappears) and the elements just one step above are those you can get by either adding $1$ to one of the terms or by adding a new term equal to $1$.  At the very bottom of the whole thing is the partition of $0$, with no terms.

Now consider the set
$$
S=\left\{\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{n}, \underbrace{2+\cdots+2}_{n-1}, \underbrace{3+\cdots+3}_{n-2},\ldots , \underbrace{{}\quad n\quad{}}_1 \right\}.
$$
For example, when $n=6$,
$$
\begin{align}
S=\{ & 1+1+1+1+1+1,\\
& 2+2+2+2+2,\\
& 3+3+3+3,\\
& 4+4+4,\\
& 5+5,\\
& 6\,\}.
\end{align}
$$
We want to look at the closure of $S$ under "going downward", i.e. the set
$$
T=\{p : \exists q\in S\ \  p\le q \}.\tag1
$$
About three years ago I read a paper by Ruedi Suter proving that the set $T$ defined in $(1)$ has certain rotational symmetries.  (Everyone has long known Young's lattice is bilaterally symmetric and it's easy to see why the set $T$ in $(1)$ is as well, but I gather Suter's discovery of rotational symmetries surprised people.)

**My question is:** Why is the cardinality of $T$ equal to $2^n$?  Or might I be mistaken in thinking that that pattern persists?

If I weren't lazy, I'd dig out Suter's paper again and see if that answers the question, and in fact I will, but it still might be interesting to see what answers people post here.

Comment: Are you assuming here that $1+1\neq2$, in other words that an expression like $1+1$ is a partition rather than a number?

Comment: Can your question be reformulated as: does the number of Young diagrams contained in a rectangle that is contained in the (triangular) diagram of $(n,n-1,\ldots,2,1)$ have $2^n$ elements, and if so why?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : Affirmative to both.  I'd forgotten the details of that paper, and I now recall that what you say was explicit in that paper, so I suspect an answer will trivially emerge from thinking about the one additional diagonal added to that triangle when going from $n$ to $n+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish the sets $S$ and $T$ for different $n,$ introduce subscripts: $S_n$ and $T_n.$  Let $T_{n,k}$ be the set of partitions in $T_n$ with largest part $k.$  The elements of $T_{n,k}$ are precisely those partitions with largest part $k$ and at most $n+1-k$ non-zero parts.  This follows from the fact that any partition that is less than a partition in $S_n$ and has largest part $k$ must be descended from a partition in $S_n$ with largest part $k$ or more, which has $n+1-k$ or fewer non-zero parts, and from the fact that any partition with largest part $k$ and at most $n+1-k$ parts can be obtained by successively subtracting $1$ from elements of
$$
\underbrace{k+\cdots+k}_{n+1-k}\in S_n.
$$

We show that $\lvert T_{n,k}\rvert=\binom{n}{k},$ from which the result follows.  This is done by showing that it satisfies the Pascal's triangle recurrence.  Clearly $\lvert T_{0,0}\rvert=1$ and $\lvert T_{n,k}\rvert=0$ for $k<0$ or $k>n.$  For $0\le k\le n,$ the elements of $T_{n,k}$ are of two types.  Type $1$ elements have only one part of size $k.$ Type $2$ elements have two or more parts of size $k.$  The Type $1$ elements are constructed by adding $1$ to the largest part of an element of $T_{n-1,k-1}.$  The Type $2$ elements are constructed by adjoining a part of size $k$ to an element of $T_{n-1,k}$.  It is easily verified (by checking inclusions in both directions), that these constructions establish bijections between the Type $1$ elements of $T_{n,k}$ and $T_{n-1,k-1}$ and between the Type $2$ elements of $T_{n,k}$ and $T_{n-1,k}.$  Therefore $\lvert T_{n,k}\rvert=\lvert T_{n-1,k-1}\rvert+\lvert T_{n-1,k}\rvert.$